# Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard buttons v and 7 randomly stop working

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, input-devices, button

I will try to explain the problem to the best of my abilities.

Some time after PC boot the <kbd>v</kbd> key and the <kbd>7</kbd> (not Num Pad) stop working. But they don't stop working completely, they work when using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and I can type small <kbd>v</kbd> if I turn on <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

When using the terminal (or text editor) the cursor blinks when these buttons are pressed, but nothing is written to the screen.

I would say that the problem is software related, like something is blocking <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> keys when pressed just by themselves.

To confirm this I tried using a virtual keyboard, then tried a different physical keyboard, changed USB ports and the behavior was always the same.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be or has had a similar problem?

I'm adding requested outputs:

```
$ xinput  
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜     ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜     ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
      ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
      ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  

$ setxkbmap -query  
rules:      evdev  
model:      pc105  
layout:     us
```

xev -event keyboard output when pressing <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>7</kbd>

```
$ xev -event keyboard
KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  81  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

xev -event keyboard output when pressing other keys

```
$ xev -event keyboard output
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x151, subw 0x0, time 102625001, (555,-208), root:(615,384),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

$ sudo evtest /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
Event: time 1532686546.734457, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70019
Event: time 1532686546.734457, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 47 (KEY_V), value 1
Event: time 1532686546.734457, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1532686546.854412, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70019
Event: time 1532686546.854412, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 47 (KEY_V), value 0
Event: time 1532686546.854412, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: Consider going to Ubuntu forums for Troubleshooting

Comment: @userDepth why not AskUbuntu? @Mita_ you can use `evtest` to see if the kernel driver produces the correct keycode, and `xev` to check if `xkb` produces the correct keysym. Which physical layout does your keyboard have?

Comment: @danzel  my keyoard has a qwerty US layout. I will add the xev output to the question.
Can you provide some info on how to use evtest?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added the requested outputs.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just added the output I got, but it's from the terminal, not the application window, because there is nothing in it.

Comment: Alright, that was helpful: the kernel doesn't deliver key events for these keys to X.org. Can you please install the `evtest` package, run `sudo evtest /dev/input/by-id/???` (replace `???` which whatever directory entry is mostly likely the keyboard by name) and do the same as for `xev` (minus the application window focus since there is none)?

Comment: Didn't realise you were talking about application focus, but at least I got the right output :)  
I added the output of xev. Seems that the keys are recognized well in here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster just to add, today when I started my PC there were some Xorg problems. First it said it couldn't detect my setting and I got a menu with a few options to use default settings, or choose them. I barely selected the option, because there was no cursor. After that the PC booted successfully and I got a system message about the crash.

Comment: Does your system have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`? If yes, their content may shed more light.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, it only has xorg.conf.failsafe

Comment: @danzel see all the messages piling down? is AskUbuntu a good interface for troubleshooting by your experience?